# Laravel 5.3 belongsToMany won't work

Tags: php, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship, laravel-5.3

I have to work with tables I didn't create so they don't follow Laravel's rules (no icremented primary key, no logical foreign and local keys, etc.). Here are my tables : **users**, **users_jobs** and **jobs**.

My pivot table, users_jobs, has a composite key (job_reference and job_node). I know Laravel don't handle composite key so I added a new field **job_key**, which is just my two keys concatenated, in users_jobs and jobs.

In my User model I have this :

```
public function jobs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Job', 'users_jobs', 'username', 'job_key');
}
```

It returns no result...

But when I try using one of my composite key it does have result. Wrong ones because it's only one of the two keys but still it works !

```
public function jobs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Job', 'users_jobs', 'username', 'job_reference');
}
```

Any clue why my new key doesn't work ?

---

Edit :

When I output the queries I have this :

> select  `jobs`.*, `users_jobs`.`username` as `pivot_username`, `users_jobs`.`job_key` as `pivot_job_key` from `jobs` inner join `users_jobs` on **`jobs`.`id`** = `users_jobs`.`job_key` where `users_jobs`.`username` in (?)

Of course it doesn't find anything, it's using *id* as foreign key rather than _job_key_ !

And I can't make it work anymore with job_reference. I know I have something wrong in my code but I can't see what and it's driving me crazy...

Comment: Can you post also your table's columns?

Comment: **users** :  `id, username, lastname, firstname, email, birthdate, etc.`

**users_jobs** : `id, username, job_key, job_reference, job_node,  startdate, enddate, comment, default, action`

**jobs** :  `id, job_key, job_reference, job_node, parent_node, node_name, active, ect.`

Comment: are username in users and job_key in jobs primary keys? to they identify the record you want to retrive?

Comment: I deleted the columns id and setted usersame and job_key as primary keys. Now I have this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select ...` I never call _id_ in my code...

Comment: If also in **users_jobs** you have that _job_key_ column is related to **jobs** and _username_ to **users**, my anwser should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';
    public function jobs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job', 'users_jobs', 'username', 'username');
    }
}

class Jobs extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'job_key';
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_jobs', 'job_key', 'job_key');
    }
}
```

Comment: My query is now correct ! Still no result but I figured out why. The username is 0000000009 and during the process it becomes 9...

Comment: It's when I set username to primearykey in the model that it changes it :(

Comment: try with `protected $casts = ['username' => 'string'];`   also, are you sure in the db the columns are of the same type?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this trait on the web, which helped me with almost the same issue that you're having here. Take a look:

```
trait HasCompositePrimaryKey {
    /**
     * Get the value indicating whether the IDs are incrementing.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIncrementing() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the keys for a save update query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query) {
        foreach ($this->getKeyName() as $key) {
            if ($this->$key)
                $query->where($key, '=', $this->$key);
            else
                throw new Exception(__METHOD__ . 'Missing part of the primary key: ' . $key);
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Use it in your model like:

```
use Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey;

protected $primaryKey = ["license_id", "trailer_id"];
```

That redefines the methods that uses the **id** field and let it accept an array.

*I didn't really check if this breaks any dark functionality of eloquent, but it's working just fine in my case.*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh great ! I'll try this out as soon as I can make my code works ;)